# Do not stop Service when Android application is swiped away from Recent Tasks

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am creating a background timer which keeps track of time since user input. This is implemented as a `Service`, started and bind through `Actvity`. What I have noticed is when the application is terminated (swiped out) through Recent Task menu, the integer counter in the service is restarted.

After further investigation I found out that the service is recreated and all previous information is lost. The service calls `onTaskRemoved` but is not destroyed. The service still keeps sending logs but with initial variable data. This is probably due to `START_STICKY` flag set which restarts the service as soon as it is stopped.

I would like to maintain the variables in the service and keep counting the counter in the background. And when the user opens application, it binds to the service and updates UI with current timer value.

As far as I see, the service is not restarted if it displays some UI element, such as Notification or Toast. In my case, I do not need any UI elements. I would like to have similar functionality like "Facebook Messenger" or "Whatsapp" where they do not show any elements and silently listen for new messages in background.

So the question is: Is it possible to maintain the service and its values and keep them running even after the user swipes away the main app from Recent Task list?

Comment: **"...a background timer which keeps track of time since user input."** - I don't follow your logic here. Why do you need a timer? If all you need is the time difference since user input, just save the time when the user last input something (use `SharedPreferences` for example) then when the user opens the app again, get current time and work out the difference.

Comment: This link helps explain what is happening but it isn't clear how to fix your problem. http://www.howtogeek.com/169549/what-exactly-happens-when-you-swipe-an-android-app-from-the-recent-apps-list/ It seems the app is closed down cleanly so you'll just have to use the life-cycle methods to recover the situation. I still think it would be better to just save the last input time in SharedPreferences and then get current time and compare the difference when the app is restarted.

Comment: Squonk, not only time difference. I need a live counter which is also kind of a scheduler which will pop-up an overlay view. When the counter reaches a specific value, the service will create a view and attach to user screen. Then after some time it will detach it and start timer again.